# D-ary heap: Intuition behind parent(int i) and child(int i) function's implementation

Tags: algorithm, heap

In D-ary heap the parent and child function are implemented like this

```
D-ARY-PARENT(i)
return (i − 2)/d + 1

D-ARY-CHILD(i, j)
return d(i − 1) + j + 1
```

Can anyone give an intuition behind these expressions?

Comment: Where did you get those expressions? Do you expect your root node to be at index 0 or at index 1? And what is `j` in the Child calculation?

Comment: Index starts from 1. second function finds j-th child of i-th node.

Comment: Those are from Kormen book.

Comment: It sounds to me more like K :) Yes

Comment: It's C actually. :)

Answer (score 0):

These functions assume that nodes are labeled in the order that breadth first search would visit them. A generic BFS algorithm looks like this:

```
initialize a queue Q = [root]
while Q is not empty
    pop the head from Q into v
    push v's children into Q
```

When the tree in question is the infinite d-ary tree, this algorithm becomes (naively)

```
initialize a queue Q = [1]
nextID = 2
forever  (Q is always nonempty)
    pop the head of Q into v
    repeat d times
        let w = nextID  (w is a child of v)
        increment nextChildID
        push w into Q
```

We observe that the sequence of IDs pushed into the queue is just 1, 2, 3, ..., so we can dispense with the queue.

```
nextParentID = 1
nextChildID = 2
forever
    let v = nextParentID
    increment nextParentID
    repeat d times
        let w = nextChildID  (w is a child of v)
        increment nextChildID
```

For `d = 3`, say, the execution over time looks like

```
nextParentID: 1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  4
nextChildID : 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

The key idea is that `nextChildID` is increasing `d` times as fast as `nextParentID`, so the relationship should be linear. I personally don't have any intuition for the constant terms other than trial and error. You can prove the formulas by induction.